# Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the below interface

```
export interface ProductCommand extends ProductDetailsCommand { }
```

ProductDetailsCommand interface

```
export interface ProductDetailsCommand {
    id: string;
    active: boolean;
    archive: boolean;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    category: CategoryVendorCommand;
    subCategory: CategoryVendorCommand;
    tags: string[];
    vendor: CategoryVendorCommand;
}
```

In the component

```
private productCommand: ProductCommand = {} as ProductCommand;
```

I am trying to assign the value of the active property

```
onMenuClick(menuItem: number, id: string): void {
    switch (menuItem) {
      case 1:
        this.productCommand.active = true;
        this.productCommand.archive = null;
        this.store.dispatch(UPDATE_PRODUCT({ id: id, product: this.productCommand }));
        break;
      case 2:
        this.productCommand.active = false;
        this.productCommand.archive = null;
        this.store.dispatch(UPDATE_PRODUCT({ id: id, product: this.productCommand }));
        break;
      case 3:
        this.productCommand.active = null;
        this.productCommand.archive = true;
        this.store.dispatch(UPDATE_PRODUCT({ id: id, product: this.productCommand }));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Exception on the second assign value, on the first assign I won't get this exception, however, on the second I got this exception

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'active' of object '[object Object]'
    at ProductDashboardTableComponent.onMenuClick (product-dashboard-table.component.ts:77)
    at ProductDashboardTableComponent_td_27_Template_button_click_16_listener (product-dashboard-table.component.html:82)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15272)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15316)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:560)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28645)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487)
```

`console.log(this.productCommand)` in the click handler:

[image]

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.productCommand)` in your click handler? To check if that's actually the object you expect it to be?

Comment: @Cerbrus included the log

Comment: It says the property is read-only. So, it's either [not writeable](https://jsbin.com/rijiwum/1/edit?js,console) or [the object is frozen](https://jsbin.com/zefahej/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set value with spread operator:

```
...
this.productCommand = {...this.productCommand, active: true};
...
```

Answer (score 0):

productCommand if you are receiving this value from store. You need to create new reference for productCommand. Since store value are read only you can change the value directly.

```
subscribe((productCommand )=>{
     this.productCommand = {...productCommand }
})
```